# Proving vectors can be decomposed to tangential and normal components

Tags: vectors

Prove that any vector $\vec{F}$ can be decomposed to tangential and normal components with respect to arbitrary vector $\vec{r}$, i.e we're looking for whether $\vec{F}=\vec{F}_\perp + \vec{F}_{||}$ is true statement

Answer (score 0):

Assume we can write:
$\vec{F}=\vec{F}_\perp + \vec{F}_{||}$
Here
 $\vec{F}_{||} = (\vec{F} \cdot \vec{a_r})\vec{a_r}$
It follows that $\vec{F}_\perp$ is given by
$\vec{F}_\perp = \vec{F}- \vec{F}_{||} = \vec{F}- (\vec{F} \cdot \vec{a_r})\vec{a_r}$
Dot producting both sides with $\vec{a_r}$ we have:
$\vec{F}_\perp \cdot \vec{a_r} =^{?}0 = \vec{F}\cdot\vec{a_r}- (\vec{F} \cdot \vec{a_r})\vec{a_r}\cdot\vec{a_r} =0 $
QED